# UWP Binding Edit Form

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I'm using SQLite-net to do CRUD, but am stuck on the binding the currently selected element in a gridview to controls in a different frame.

CustomClass.cs

```
using ProjectName.SQLite;

namespace ProjectName.Models
{
    public class CustomClass
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Column("CustomText")]
        public string CustomText { get; set; }
    }

}

public static class SQLiteDataManager
{
    private static SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("localdatabase.db");

    public async static Task Create()
    {
        await conn.CreateTableAsync<CustomClass>();
    }

    public async static Task Drop()
    {
        await conn.DropTableAsync<CustomClass>();
    }

    public async static Task Add(CustomClass temp)
    {
        await conn.InsertAsync(temp);
    }

    public async static Task Delete(CustomClass temp)
    {
        await conn.Delete(temp);
    }

    public async static Task Select(ObservableCollection<CustomClass> temp)
    {
        temp.Clear();

        var results = await conn.Table<CustomClass>().ToListAsync();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            temp.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

app.xaml.cs - Storing an instance to reference between frames

```
using ProjetName.Models;

namespace ProjetName
{
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public static CustomClass selectedGridViewItem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewItemsFrame.xaml.cs - when the grid view is selected, the app level instance of the variable is updated.  The edit button shows the edit frame after an item is selected in the gridview.

```
    private void butEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditItemFrame));
    }

    private void gvData_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        App.selectedGridViewItem = (CustomClass)e.ClickedItem;
    }
```

EditItemFrame.xaml - edit form shows data from the selected item in the gridview from the previous frame

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:EditViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="butSave" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE105;" FontSize="12" RelativePanel.LeftOf="butCancel" Click="butSave_Click" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="46" Height="31" />
        <Button Name="butCancel" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE0D5;" FontSize="12" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Click="butCancel_Click" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="46" Height="31" />
        <TextBlock Text="Text stuff: "/>
        <TextBox Name="txtStuff" Text="{Binding ManageCustom.CustomText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

EditItemFrame.xaml.cs

```
using ProjectName;

namespace ProjectName
{
    public sealed partial class EditItemsFrame : Page
    {
        CustomClass editedcustom;

        public EditCustom()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            editedcustom = App.selectedGridViewItem;
        }

        private void butSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void butCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(ViewItemsFrame));
        }
    }
}
```

EditViewModel.cs - When the edit form shows, the textbox is binded/populated with the SelectedGridItem variable, but the two way doesn't work.  Shouldn't it save automatically with two way?  Or should I just scrap the View Model/binding all together and assign the textbox/listbox/calendar/etc values on frame load?

```
using ProjectName;
using ProjectName.Models;

namespace ProjectName.ViewModel
{
    class EditViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public CustomClass ManageCustom {
            get { return App.selectedGridViewItem; }
            set {
                App.selectedGridViewItem = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(App.selectedGridViewItem)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: who will be updating the 'CustomText' property and when? if it will update after the edit form is shown then 'CustomText' must notify its change too.

Comment: The CustomText property in App.selectedGridViewItem should be updated by the txtStuff textblock onchange event on the EditItemFrame form.

Comment: What do you want with this line `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(App.selectedGridViewItem)));`?

Comment: Got it from some sample code, uncertain of it's usefulness.  MVVM is new for me.